# Ruby - Substitute root of path for new root path

Tags: ruby, string, file, path

Okay, so I want to take a file path that I have, remove a known root path, and append a new one.

I will attempt to make an example:

```
# This one is a path object
original_path = '/home/foo/bar/path/to/file.txt'
# This one is a string
root_path = '/home/foo/bar/'
# This is also a string
new_root = '/home/new/root/'
```

So, I have `original_path`, which is a path object. And I want to remove `root_path` from this, and apply `new_root` to the front of it. How can I do this?

EDIT:

This is my real problem, sorry for the poor explaination before:

```
require 'pathname'

# This one is a path object
original_path = Pathname.new('/home/foo/bar/path/to/file.txt')
# This one is a string
root_path = '/home/foo/bar/'
# This is also a string
new_root = '/home/new/root/'
```

Now how do you substitute those?

Comment: Are you trying to move the file to a new location or just change the string value of the path?

Comment: I updated my issue above. I am creating a filetype converter. Basically I have a pathname, and I want to change the root directory so I can 'recreate' the structure of a directory somewhere else with the converted files inside.

Comment: So you want to copy all files in `root_path` to `new_root`? This is much more complicated than what you are describing.

Comment: Not necessarily copy them directly, but run them through a function first and spit them out with a new extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to get a new string, you can do this

```
# This one is a path object
original_path = '/home/foo/bar/path/to/file.txt'
# This one is a string
root_path = '/home/foo/bar/'
# This is also a string
new_root = '/home/new/root/'

new_path = original_path.gsub(root_path, new_root)
```

Edit

You can still use `sub` instead of `gsub` if `original_path` is a `Pathname`

```
new_path = original_path.sub(root_path, new_root)
```

Comment: Sorry, I update my issue above, so it is not as simple as this.

Comment: Thank you! Using your solutions I was able to fix my larger issue.